# libGDX FitViewport works not on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have this approach which works and scales as expected on Windows Desktop:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch m_batch;
    FitViewport m_viewport;
    OrthographicCamera m_camera;

    private Texture img;
    private BitmapFont m_font;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_NONE);

        m_batch = new SpriteBatch();

        m_camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        m_camera.position.set(640 / 2f, 400 / 2f, 0);
        m_camera.update();
        m_viewport = new FitViewport(640, 400, m_camera);

        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

        m_font = new BitmapFont();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        m_batch.begin();
        m_font.draw(m_batch, "X000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000X", 0, m_camera.viewportHeight);
        m_batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        m_batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        m_viewport.update(width, height);
    }
}
```

Initial Window Size:
[image: 01]

Bigger Window Size
[image: 02]

But if I deploy to Android (in this case Nexus 7 2013) it seems not to scale properly:
[image: 03]

Why does it not work? How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to use the camera in your sprite batch. Call

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
```

before `spriteBatch.begin();`.